# Selenium выгружает нужный webelement методом .find_element но метод .text ничего не возвращает

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Нужно выгрузить характеристики товара с озона (конкретно цену)
Нашел их в этом блоке:
[image: Код сайта]

Код написал такой. Причем работает только метод XPath,  все остальные выдают ошибку "Элемент не найден"

```
try:
driver.get('https://www.ozon.ru/product/napolnye-vesy-umnye-chernye-1423887375')
time.sleep(20)
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/head/script[@type='application/ld+json']")
print(search_box)
```

Выдает абракадабру (как я понял в виде web element'a)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке добавить метод .text

```
try:
driver.get('https://www.ozon.ru/product/napolnye-vesy-umnye-chernye-1423887375')
time.sleep(20)
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/head/script[@type='application/ld+json']").text
print(search_box)
```

Код выполняется без ошибок, но не выдает ничего
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помочь разобраться сданной проблемой. В идеале выгружать сразу в виде словаря, но попытка прикрутить сюда json ни к чему не привела.
Также прошу подсказать какие значения нужно вводить в методы find_element'a ID, LINK_TEXT, чтобы они работали для данного элемента

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Не ужели наделать скриншотов было быстрее чем просто вставить код текстом?)

Comment: Код не выводился нормально почему то. Решил, что проще скрины сделать. Заменил скрины кода на сам код.  except и finally убрал т.к. они нормально не выводились как код.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks